# TIFF flipped along X-axis when reprojecting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing

I’m very new to GIS software and am having some trouble. I’ve looked for the answer to this question elsewhere but can’t seem to find it. Can you point me to it?

I’m trying to create a custom fantasy map for a personal project. I created a custom DEM (16-bit grayscale .tif) and have successfully manipulated the symbology, etc. But there are some more things I’d like to do with it that require it be reprojected. When I do this, I get “transformation is already set to north up…specify SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM…” When I do this, the projection executes, however, the new TIFF is flipped along its upper edge. I’m not sure how to fix this. I’ve attached an image of the information panel of the reprojected raster.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: how are you  reprojecting the raster?